# MS Word does not unlink fields for one document but does for another

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have some VBA code (In Excel) that will open a Word document, break the links, and save that Word document elsewhere.
All automated and transport to the user, all they will see is a file appear in a folder.

My problem is it works for the below:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()

Dim objWord As Object
Dim docWord As Object
Const wdDoNotSaveChanges As Long = 0
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set docWord = objWord.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\A folder\Myfile.doc")

objWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Unlink

objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" + Cells(1, 7) + "myfile.doc"

objWord.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
objWord.Quit

End Sub
```

but not for the below which is supposed to perform the same function on a different Word document:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click()

Dim objWord As Object
Dim docWord As Object
Const wdDoNotSaveChanges As Long = 0
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set docWord = objWord.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\A Folder\Myfile2.doc")

objWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Unlink

objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" + Cells(1, 7) + "MyFile2.doc"

objWord.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
objWord.Quit

End Sub
```

When I open the first document generated (outcome of the first code), it doesn't ask me to update the links and the links are broken, as intended.

When I open the second document generated (Outcome of the second code), it asks me to update the links.

EDIT:

Both sections of code above have been merged and put into a single sub that has variables forwarded to it - Still same outcome of one document updating and unlinking as intended, the other document asking the user on opening if they want to update links.

So now most likely a problem with the Word documents.

Both Word documents are linked to Excel via Paste Special > Paste Link.

Both only linked to the one Excel document.

The only difference I can see is one document has quite a few more links than the other, but surely quantity of links shouldn't matter?

Comment: Perhaps; `Set docWord = objWord.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Myfile2.doc", UpdateLinks:=False)` Or `True` if you do want links updated

Comment: Why would you use identical code in 2 places?  Convert it to a `Sub`, then call ***that*** from your click handlers.

Comment: The file that is opened and the filepath where they are saved to is the only difference between each instance. I have simplified the paths just for this example.

Comment: You can still use a sub as Comintern has suggested and just pass a variable to it. The point is here that you're going the wrong way about this - and fwiw I suspect the other document is the cause of your issue - not the code

Comment: Code sustainability (while it is important) isnt what Demo has asked for, the question is to not have a message to update links when opening a word doc .. Probably

Comment: Correct, the links should be broken before saving (As I do not want them updated or the user being asked to update), I have made a sub and the 2 buttons now call from this sub while sending the file path in a variable. Same problem. What could be causing this? the Word documents are simply linked via "paste special > paste link"

Comment: What does Cells(1, 7) contain in each of the two Excels?

Comment: @z32a7ul A name. The documents need to be named by a persons name plus a description, which I have simplified for the example as `MyFile`

Comment: Can you open the second document and check if you can see links in the user interface: Office Button > Prepare > Edit Links to Files? If you see the links, choose to break them, and reopen the document, does it ask the question again?

Comment: @z32a7ul I have opened the document, broken the links, saved, then used to the code to generate another document. Didn't ask to update links. I have added a single link back to it and generated another document, it once again asks me to update links upon opening.

Comment: Looking at the document that has been generated from the original, the single link I have added is still visible in `Edit Links To Files` section. So it is present in both original and generated document. Alternatively, the document that DOES work has the links present on the original an removed on the generated. Yet both function off the same sun with `objWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Unlink`

Comment: And what is the Type of these if they exist? I mean, they your document may contain e.g. charts, which are not fields, so Unlink does not refer to them.

Comment: They are simply individual cells copied, then into Word > Paste Special > Paste Link > Formatted Text

Comment: Upon further investigation, the problem is confined to the header of the document. My code will unlink all fields in the body of the document, but will not do this for the header. As a result, the header remains linked and it asks the user if they would like to update. I need a way of unlinking the header.

Comment: Solved my own issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829402/vba-excel-unlink-headers-footers-in-word/42904156#42904156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation, the problem is confined to the header of the document. My code will unlink all fields in the body of the document, but will not do this for the header. As a result, the header remains linked and it asks the user if they would like to update.

I eventually found my solution here:
[VBA Excel - Unlink headers & footers in Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829402/vba-excel-unlink-headers-footers-in-word/42904156#42904156)